# how can I write a file location with space and slash in applescript?

Tags: applescript

Here below is the **applescript**:

```
do script ("aria2c -i /Users/mac/Downloads/aria2c\ \(1\).down") in currentTab
```

The expected result in **shell** would like this:

```
~$ aria2c -i /Users/mac/Downloads/aria2c\ \(1\).down
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppleScript a backslash must be escaped with a second one:

```
do script ("aria2c -i /Users/mac/Downloads/aria2c\\ \\(1\\).down") in currentTab
```

A smarter way is `quoted form of`, it magically adds all necessary backslashes / quotation characters

```
do script "aria2c -i " & quoted form of "/Users/mac/Downloads/aria2c (1).down" in currentTab
```